# How to instantiate an array inside nested objects in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, object

I'm trying to assign a value to property of an object inside a complex object with nested types. One of the types is an Array. And that is where I am getting stuck. I have a complex object with many nested objects. One of the objects is an Array[]. I am trying to assign the request parameter *accountNumber* to the **AccountNumber** property of **AccountKeyType**. But I am stuck on initializing the AccountType array Object. Here is my class structure:

```
    public class Customer
{
    public AccountType[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

public partial class AccountType
{
    public AccountKeyType AccountKey { get; set; }
}

public class AccountKeyType
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where I am getting stuck:

```
                        Customer = new Customer
                    {
                        Accounts = new AccountType[0]
                        {
        //How do I access the nested object **AccountKeyType.AccountNumber** like this:
            //AccountKeyType.AccountNumber = request.AccountNumber
                        }
                    }
```

**Update: This is the fix:

```
                        Customer = new Customer
                    {

                        Accounts = new AccountType[]
                        {
                            new AccountType() { AccountKey = new AccountKeyType()
                                {
                                  AccountNumber=request.AccountNumber
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: You can't index into an array that doesn't exist yet. You need to populate it with `AccountType`s and access the props there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate an `AccountType` in your `AccountType[]`

```
Customer = new Customer
{
    Accounts = new AccountType[]
    {
        new AccountType() { AccountNumber = request.AccountNumber }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to instantiate multiple

```
Customer = new Customer
{
    Accounts = new AccountType[]
    {
        new AccountType() { AccountNumber = accountNumber1 },
        new AccountType() { AccountNumber = accountNumber2 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add an example with 2 for clarity. Nice answer.

Comment: This was the way. Thank you so much!